# Rename a specific url parameter and its value htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to replace a specific url parameter and it's value in htaccess per modrewrite:

OLD:

```
/index.php?id=364&lang=de
/index.php?id=364&lang=en
```

NEW:

```
/index.php?id=364&L=0
/index.php?id=364&L=1
```

Any hints for this?

I tried this, but it's not for the value itself. Sorry, I'm not so fit in mod_rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?L=%1 [L,R]
```

Thanks and all the best,

Chris

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: We are not here for you to “outsource” stuff like this completely to us. Start by doing a bit of proper research - stuff like this has been discussed before, you should be able to find enough material to at least make an attempt.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I forgot to add my try, but as I told above, I'm not so fit in the rewrite stuff. I don't know how to switch the value of the param by condition.

Comment: The server can not guess that you want `0` replaced with `de`, and `1` with `en`. So you will have to handle both cases separately, and then explicitly have the `de` and `en` hardcoded as part of your substitution URL.

Comment: Plus, you currently got it the wrong way around. If your _old_ URL contains `L=0`, then that is what you need to match via the RewriteCond, and the RewriteRule has to rewrite to the new URL where the parameter is named `lang`.

Comment: Allright and thanks, the try from me just cuts out the other params out of the string... Means, that ?id=364 is missing after the redirect. Must step further into this thing. I'm always struggling with mod_rewrite once a year! I don't need them so often.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, please try following. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewiteEngine ON
##Rule for internal rewrite to index.php for de language.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index\.php)\?id=(\d+)&lang(de)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?id=%2&L=0 [L]
####Rule for internal rewrite to index.php for en language.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index\.php)\?id=(\d+)&lang(en)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?id=%2&L=1 [L]
```

Comment: @ChrisBernhard, could you please do let me know if this helps you, thank you.